# Padding and class col-md not working

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am trying to shift my radio button to the right for this certain part for a long time and it still doesn't work, I try using padding and class col-md for it and even check if my tag are closed but it is still not moving to the right. Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

test.blade.php

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2"><b>Residential Status:</b></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="radio" name="residential_status" value="Local" required> Local<br>
        <input type="radio" name="residential_status" value="Overseas" required> Overseas<br>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="editfield1">
        <div class="radio">
          <div id="chkNRICid1">
          <label style="font-weight: bold">Do you have a NRIC?</label> <br/>
              <input type="radio" name="NRIC_check" id="nricid1" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('NRIC_check').style.display='block'" required> Yes <br>
              <input type="radio" name="NRIC_check" id="nricid2" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('NRIC_check').style.display='none'" required> No 
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="editfield1" id="NRIC_check" style="display:none">
        <label for="NRIC_check"> Type your NRIC/FIN number:</label>
              <label><input type="text" name="nric_number1" id="nric_number1"> </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the screenshot of what is happening: (I want it to be like the Residential Status)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many wayward and un-needed divs you can get rid of along with fixing your nesting, after that it's just a matter of following the structure in the first part of your template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Residential Status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label><input type="radio" name="residential_status" value="Local" required> Local</label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="residential_status" value="Overseas" required> Overseas</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Do you have a NRIC?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label><input type="radio" name="NRIC_check" id="nricid1" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('NRIC_check').style.display='block'" required>Yes</label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="NRIC_check" id="nricid2" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('NRIC_check').style.display='none'" required> No </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="NRIC_check" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Type your NRIC/FIN number:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="nric_number1" id="nric_number1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your right, by removing those unwanted divs it work, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two inputs inside a `<div>` and add some margin.

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px">
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
</div>
```

If you are using Bootstrap 4 you could even:

```
<div class="ml-5">
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i tried doing that but the result was the same as the div class col-md where it just shift the radio button near the "you" part of the "Do you have a NRIC"